# Python code doesn't execute. No errors showed

Tags: python

I don't know what's wrong with my code. It would just not execute. Nothing happens, no errors occur. I can't figure it out. 
If someone can tell me what I have done wrong, please do so and I will be grateful.

```
class Money (object):
    def __init__ (self, euro, cent):
      self.euro = euro
      self.cent = cent

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.cent >= 100:
            r = self.cent / 100
            self.cent = self.cent % 100
            self.euro = self.euro + r
            return ("%d EUR & %d cents") % (self.euro, self.cent)
        else:
            return ("%d EUR & %d cents") % (self.euro, self.cent)

    def changeCent (self):
        #100 c = 1 E
        cents = self.euro * 100
        self.cent = self.cent + cents
        return self.cent

    def changeSum (self, euros):
        #1 E = 100 c
        euros = self.cent / 100
        self.euro = self.euro + euros
        return self.euro

    def debt (self, years, rate):
        value = Money()
        multiply = rate * years * 12 / 100
        value.euro = self.euro * multiply
        value.cent = self.cent * multiply
        if value.cent > 100:
            euro_ = value.cent / 100
            value.cent = value.cent - 100
            value.euro = value.euro + euro_
        return value

def main():
    x = Money()
    x.euro = int(input("Type in your EURO ammount: \n"))
    x.cent = int(input("Type in your CENT ammount: \n"))
    print (x)
```

Comment: You've defined a class and a `main` function. Are you running the function?

Comment: You should have started with a `Hello World` program and extended it from there.

Comment: Uhm, I dunno. I thought 'def main()' was to create a border between the class and its methods/functions and the main program itself.

Comment: Are you thinking of `main` from `C/C++`?

Comment: @AngelDraghici A class is something that helps organize/encapsulate logic inside of a script - same with methods (like `main()`).  But for the script to run, you have to call some method, or class property.  Otherwise, you've written a function library - not a script that does anything on its own.

Comment: Solved, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the main function, but you never call it.

add `main()` to the end of your code.

It then runs but there are errors, to fix the errors, change your `main()` function to

```
def main()
    euro = int(input("Type in your EURO ammount: \n"))
    cent = int(input("Type in your CENT ammount: \n"))
    x = Money(euro, cent)
    print (x)
```

Full working code:

```
class Money (object):
    def __init__ (self, euro, cent):
      self.euro = euro
      self.cent = cent

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.cent >= 100:
            r = self.cent / 100
            self.cent = self.cent % 100
            self.euro = self.euro + r
            return ("%d EUR & %d cents") % (self.euro, self.cent)
        else:
            return ("%d EUR & %d cents") % (self.euro, self.cent)

    def changeCent (self):
        #100 c = 1 E
        cents = self.euro * 100
        self.cent = self.cent + cents
        return self.cent

    def changeSum (self, euros):
        #1 E = 100 c
        euros = self.cent / 100
        self.euro = self.euro + euros
        return self.euro

    def debt (self, years, rate):
        value = Money()
        multiply = rate * years * 12 / 100
        value.euro = self.euro * multiply
        value.cent = self.cent * multiply
        if value.cent > 100:
            euro_ = value.cent / 100
            value.cent = value.cent - 100
            value.euro = value.euro + euro_
        return value

def main():
    euro = int(input("Type in your EURO ammount: \n"))
    cent = int(input("Type in your CENT ammount: \n"))
    x = Money(euro, cent)
    print (x)

main()
```

Comment: @AngelDraghici No problem! :)

Comment: @AngelDraghici If my answer solved your problem, please accept my answer with the green tick mark near the upvote and downvote buttons. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 6):

In python, `main` is not a special function (unlike C, for example).

You need to explicitly call `main()` in your script.

A common idiom is to only do this if your file is run as a script (as opposed to being imported):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) for how this works

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way of getting a result here would be to add following lines to the file:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

It checks, whether you are calling the script as the main script.
Currently you only define the function main, but you never call it.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the function main()

Answer (score 0):

To execute the function type `main()` at the bottom. You did almost everything except calling the function.

One more mistake

your constructor 
 `def __init__ (self, euro, cent):`expects two parameters. You are not  passing any value to it.

To fix that change to:

```
def __init__ (self, euro=0, cent=0):
```

which assigns default value of 0 to both `euro` and `cent`

Comment: Thank you, misunderstanding the `main()` method with the main from C/C++.

Comment: Adding the `euro=0, cent=0` Is not the right solution